# AWS S3 not stops uploading from my Lenovo® ix2-dl

Tags: api, amazon-s3, nas

I have a NAS drive Lenovo® ix2-dl that I set up to back up to AWS S3. It connected fine. But for some reason it only uploads 5% of my Lenovo® ix2-dl Data. How can I get it to upload my whole Lenovo® ix2-dl Data?

Answer (score 0):

I updated my NAS to the latest Firmware 4.1.218.34037.

I recently had issues with the s3 backup feature, where the uploads simply stopped working. No errors, nothing in logs to indicate an issue. I tested by AWS S3 access key and secret with another method and was able to upload files just fine.

To resolve the issue, i had to create a new AWS S3 bucket, then go into the S3 setup of Lenovo and provide the required info. I think what made this work for me, was i made sure to not have anything in the bucket name other than letters and numbers. My bucket name before was similar to this lastname.family.pics, my new bucket which works is similar to this lastname123.

Hope this helps, this feature has worked fine for a long time, perhaps an update came down which has different requirements for the api.